# How I can check that unique data in pivot table already exists?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 I have table pivot table defined :

```
    Schema::create('article_vote', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        $table->foreignId('vote_id')->references('id')->on('votes')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        $table->unique(['vote_id', 'article_id'], 'article_vote_vote_id_article_id_index');
        ...
    });
```

and having in both models methods with  belongsToMany
I can refer articles of a vote as :
$voteArticles = $vote->articles;

When I want to add some more data I do

```
$vote->articles()->attach($articleId, $data);
```

But if in database there are already data with article_id / vote_id I got Duplicate entry error.

In which way I can check that such data in article_vote already exists ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend checking before you insert. You end up doing what the database will do anyway which is to check if the integrity contstraints are still satisfied. I suggest you wrap the `attach` code in a `try ... catch` to catch the PDO exception that indicates there's a duplicate entry and handle it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this before calling attach.

```
if (!$vote->articles()->where('article_id', $articleId)->exists()) {
    $vote->articles()->attach($articleId, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `syncWithoutDetaching` instead of `attach`.

```php
$vote->articles()->syncWithoutDetaching([$articleId => $data]);
```